# AWS SNS - iOS endpoints not becoming disabled when the app is uninstalled

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns, endpoint

I am using AWS SNS to send push notifications to all of my Android and iOS devices.

On Android when I send push notification to all my devices, SNS correctly disables inactive endpoints, i.e. endpoints pointing to the app which was uninstalled by the user.

However, on iOS, this is not working. Even if a user deletes the app and then I send a push notification to all devices - the endpoint is still enabled. On iOS endpoints never become disabled even if the app is uninstalled.

Does anyone have any idea, why endpoints are not getting disabled on iOS devices?